# Running puppet cert list doesn't show certificate I'm looking for

Tags: linux, puppet

I'm on CentOS 6.4

On the first attempt of listing certificates from puppet master server, when I run `puppet cert list` it shows the certificate.

But after few days later it doesn't show the certificate.

Puppet services are running fine, what could be the issue?

Answer (score 4):

According to specification about `puppet cert list` [command:](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/3.3.1/man/cert.html)

> List outstanding certificate requests. If '--all' is specified, signed certificates are also listed, prefixed by '+', and revoked or
>   invalid certificates are prefixed by '-' (the verification outcome is
>   printed in parenthesis).

So you see certificate at first, because it wasn't signed by master. After signing it will  not be listed unless you call:

```
puppet cert list --all
```